# SQL Server 2022 Graph - Entity developer against T-SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, devart, sql-graph

I create a database from scratch using T-SQL (this code works).

As we can see, the graph use $node_id in T-SQL which looks like an alias of the full name $NodeIdE051E8F24C3E4C19A168DDEF0BAA40A7.
This unique ID changes each time I create the DB. The T-SQL script always works.

```
CREATE DATABASE TestGraph

ALTER DATABASE TestGraph MODIFY FILE
( NAME = N'TestGraph', SIZE = 32MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 5MB )
GO

ALTER DATABASE TestGraph MODIFY FILE
( NAME = N'TestGraph_log', SIZE = 32MB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10% )
GO

use "TestGraph"
go

exec sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1
go
reconfigure
go

alter database "TestGraph"
set containment = partial
go

CREATE USER testuser WITH PASSWORD = '$Password1234'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'testuser';
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'testuser';
go

CREATE TABLE Species 
(
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TranslatedNameId] int NULL,
    [ImageIndex] int NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(64),
    [Description] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
) AS NODE;

CREATE TABLE ChildSpeciesLink AS EDGE;
CREATE TABLE AncestorSpeciesLink AS EDGE;

Insert Species (Name, Description) VALUES 
(N'Racine', N'Racine de l''arbre.'),
(N'Chat', N'Chat'),
(N'Chien', N'Chien'),
(N'Furet', N'Furet'),
(N'Rat', N'Rat');

Insert into ChildSpeciesLink ($to_id,$from_id) values

-- Race Chat:
(
    (select $node_id from dbo.Species where Id=1),
    (select $node_id from dbo.Species where Id=2)
),
-- Race Chien:
(
    (select $node_id from dbo.Species where Id=1),
    (select $node_id from dbo.Species where Id=3)
);

Insert into AncestorSpeciesLink ($to_id,$from_id) values
-- Race Chat:
(
    (select $node_id from dbo.Species where Id=2),
    (select $node_id from dbo.Species where Id=1)
),
-- Race Chien:
(
    (select $node_id from dbo.Species where Id=3),
    (select $node_id from dbo.Species where Id=1)
);
```

But the problem is after, with Entity Developer. The generated class use the full name so I must resync C# code on database and rebuild project. Is there a way to avoid this ?

Here is the generated code :

```
public partial class Species 
{
        public Species()
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public string NodeIdE051E8F24C3E4C19A168DDEF0BAA40A7 { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clé primaire.
        /// </summary>
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Numéro de ressource externe pour la localisation.
        /// </summary>
        public int? TranslatedNameId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Numéro d&apos;image pour un rendu plus visuel de la donnée.
        /// </summary>
        public int? ImageIndex { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Nom de l&apos;espèce concernée.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        #region Extensibility Method Definitions

        partial void OnCreated();

        #endregion
}
```

Thanks for help.
Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will add the feature of detecting and truncating the GUID suffix in columns' names when importing graph tables into Devart EF Core Model and notify you.